# Inconsistent auto-decoding with spring @RequestParam

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test

I have a normal spring @Controller which takes an URL-encoded string as parameter:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/wechat/browser", method = GET)
public void askWeChatWhoTheUserIs(@RequestParam(name = "origin") String origin,
                                  HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    //omitted codes
}
```

When I debug the spring boot application and test the endpoint with browser:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/wechat/browser\?origin\=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Findex.html%3Fa%3Db%23%2Froute
```

The `origin` got decoded automatically and equal to `http://www.example.com/index.html?a=b#/route`

But when I wrote a spring mvc test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(WeChatOauthController.class)
public class WeChatOauthControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void itShouldRedirectToWeChatToFinishOauthProtocol() throws Exception {

        String origin = "http://www.example.com/index.html?a=b#/route";
        String encodedOrigin = URLEncoder.encode(origin, "UTF-8");

        this.mvc.perform(get("/wechat/browser")
            .param("origin", encodedOrigin))
            .andDo(print())
        //omitted codes
    }
}
```

When I debug this test and the controller, the `origin` was not decoded this time. Just wondering why it behaves differently in these two cases.

Comment: _"Just wondering why it behaves differently in these two cases"_ In one case you have a server, in the other one not. In one case you have a fully configured application, in the other one not. You probably have to configure URL-Decoding for your tests as well.

Comment: @zeroflagL makes sense, with spring boot, I actually have an embedded tomcat server. Could u elaborate on how to configure URL?

Answer (score 1):

When supplying a request parameter with the Spring MVC Test framework, there is no need to manually encode the parameter's value since there is no physical HTTP request.

So, just use the `original` *raw* value in your test, and it should work fine.

In other words, use this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(WeChatOauthController.class)
public class WeChatOauthControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void itShouldRedirectToWeChatToFinishOauthProtocol() throws Exception {
        this.mvc.perform(get("/wechat/browser")
            .param("origin", "http://www.example.com/index.html?a=b#/route"))
            .andDo(print())
        //omitted codes
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, understand. Just worried that the test does not reveal the intention and  probably cause misunderstanding about how to use this endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method , thus there will be proper decoding

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class WeChatOauthControllerTest {

 @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    TestRestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();

  @Test
    public void testAmpersandEncoded(){
        ResponseEntity<String> response = 
        restTemplate.exchange(createURI("%26"),HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
        assertEquals(response.getStatusCode(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

  private URI createURI(String param){
        URI uri = null;
        String url = "http://localhost:"+ port +"/location?query=" + param;
        try {
            uri = new URI(url);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
           log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return uri;
    }
```